# highlight "starred" comments by admin

Tags: comments

I'm looking for a **wordpress plugin, hook function or directions** for these specific needs (I'm okay writing my own plugin):

- when moderating comments, a wordpress admin should be able to change its status (approved/pending/spam, like usual) and "star this comment" or set its status to a new status "approved and starred"
- These "starred" comments would show up **highlighted**, **sorted first** or **diplayed in a tab-like interface** on the post page

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/highlight-comments/ Give it a try.